# $push filtered items in $group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, push

How can I $push filtered records in $group? I need to do something like:

```
db.products.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$designs' },
    { $group: {
        _id: { '$_id' },
        data_1: { $push: {$designs: {$where: <condition1>}} },
        data_2: { $push: {$designs: {$where: <condition2>}} }
    }}
)
```

Comment: do you need to simply update an array within one of your documents?

Comment: I need to select designs grouped by condition using one query.

Comment: What's the actual criteria to be used in the condition?

Comment: Can you show us a sample document?